# most KDE apps stopped working after update

Tags: linux, debian, kde

I updated my Debian Testing today to Plasma version 4:5.14.5.1 and then tried standby mode. As I started the PC again (it was seemingly properly shutdown) the system tray icons vanished and the search with Alt+Space did only show contacts. Also when rightclicking on a widget there is no context menu anymore. I can't use my PC normally now anymore, what happend? I tried restarting multiple times already but everything stays the same.

after the update:

```
Versions of packages plasma-workspace depends on:
ii  dbus-user-session [default-dbus-session-bus]  1.12.16-1
ii  dbus-x11 [dbus-session-bus]                   1.12.16-1
ii  drkonqi                                       5.14.5-1
ii  frameworkintegration                          5.62.0-1
ii  gdb-minimal [gdb]                             8.3-1
ii  iso-codes                                     4.3-1
ii  kactivitymanagerd                             5.14.5-1
ii  kded5                                         5.62.0-1
ii  kinit                                         5.62.0-1
ii  kio                                           5.62.1-1
ii  kpackagetool5                                 5.62.0-1
ii  kwin-common                                   4:5.14.5-1
ii  libappstreamqt2                               0.12.9-1
ii  libc6                                         2.29-2
ii  libcolorcorrect5                              4:5.14.5.1-2
ii  libgcc1                                       1:9.2.1-8
ii  libgps23                                      3.17-7
ii  libice6                                       2:1.0.9-2
ii  libkf5activities5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5authcore5                               5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5baloo5                                  5.62.0-2
ii  libkf5bookmarks5                              5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5calendarevents5                         5.54.0-1
ii  libkf5completion5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5config-bin                              5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5configcore5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5configgui5                              5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5configwidgets5                          5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5coreaddons5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5crash5                                  5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5dbusaddons5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5declarative5                            5.54.0-1
ii  libkf5globalaccel-bin                         5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5globalaccel5                            5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5guiaddons5                              5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5holidays5                               1:5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5i18n5                                   5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5iconthemes5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5idletime5                               5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5itemviews5                              5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5jobwidgets5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5js5                                     5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5jsembed5                                5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5kdelibs4support5                        5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5kiocore5                                5.62.1-1
ii  libkf5kiofilewidgets5                         5.62.1-1
ii  libkf5kiogui5                                 5.62.1-1
ii  libkf5kiowidgets5                             5.62.1-1
ii  libkf5networkmanagerqt6                       5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5newstuff5                               5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5notifications5                          5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5notifyconfig5                           5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5package5                                5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5plasma5                                 5.54.0-1
ii  libkf5plasmaquick5                            5.54.0-1
ii  libkf5prison5                                 5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5quickaddons5                            5.54.0-1
ii  libkf5runner5                                 5.54.0-1
ii  libkf5service-bin                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5service5                                5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5solid5                                  5.62.0-2
ii  libkf5texteditor5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5textwidgets5                            5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5wallet-bin                              5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5wallet5                                 5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5waylandclient5                          4:5.62.0-2
ii  libkf5widgetsaddons5                          5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5windowsystem5                           5.62.0-2
ii  libkf5xmlgui5                                 5.62.0-1
ii  libkscreenlocker5                             5.14.5-1
ii  libksgrd7                                     4:5.14.5-1
ii  libkworkspace5-5                              4:5.14.5.1-2
ii  libphonon4qt5-4                               4:4.10.3-3
ii  libplasma-geolocation-interface5              4:5.14.5.1-2
ii  libprocesscore7                               4:5.14.5-1
ii  libprocessui7                                 4:5.14.5-1
ii  libqalculate20                                2.8.2-1+b1
ii  libqt5core5a                                  5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libqt5dbus5                                   5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libqt5gui5                                    5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libqt5network5                                5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libqt5qml5                                    5.11.3-4
ii  libqt5quick5                                  5.11.3-4
ii  libqt5sql5                                    5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libqt5widgets5                                5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libqt5x11extras5                              5.11.3-2
ii  libqt5xml5                                    5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libsm6                                        2:1.2.3-1
ii  libstdc++6                                    9.2.1-8
ii  libtaskmanager6                               4:5.14.5.1-2
ii  libweather-ion7                               4:5.14.5.1-2
ii  libx11-6                                      2:1.6.8-1
ii  libxcb-composite0                             1.13.1-2
ii  libxcb-damage0                                1.13.1-2
ii  libxcb-image0                                 0.4.0-1+b2
ii  libxcb-randr0                                 1.13.1-2
ii  libxcb-util0                                  0.3.8-3+b2
ii  libxcb1                                       1.13.1-2
ii  libxfixes3                                    1:5.0.3-1
ii  libxrender1                                   1:0.9.10-1
ii  libxtst6                                      2:1.2.3-1
ii  milou                                         4:5.14.5-1
ii  phonon4qt5                                    4:4.10.3-3
ii  plasma-framework                              5.54.0-1
ii  plasma-integration                            5.14.5-1
ii  qdbus-qt5                                     5.11.3-4
ii  qml-module-org-kde-draganddrop                5.54.0-1
ii  qml-module-org-kde-kcoreaddons                5.54.0-1
ii  qml-module-org-kde-kholidays                  1:5.62.0-1
ii  qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols             5.54.0-1
ii  qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons       5.54.0-1
ii  qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem              5.54.0-1
ii  qml-module-org-kde-solid                      5.62.0-2
ii  qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel            5.11.3-4
ii  qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects                 5.11.3-2
ii  qml-module-qtqml-models2                      5.11.3-4
ii  qml-module-qtquick-controls                   5.11.3-2
ii  qml-module-qtquick-dialogs                    5.11.3-2
ii  qml-module-qtquick-layouts                    5.11.3-4
ii  qml-module-qtquick-window2                    5.11.3-4
ii  qml-module-qtquick2                           5.11.3-4
ii  udisks2                                       2.8.4-1
ii  x11-utils                                     7.7+4
ii  x11-xserver-utils                             7.7+8
ii  zlib1g                                        1:1.2.11.dfsg-1+b1

Versions of packages plasma-workspace recommends:
ii  kde-cli-tools    4:5.14.5-1
ii  kio-extras       4:19.08.1-1
ii  ksysguardd       4:5.14.5-1
ii  libpam-kwallet5  5.14.5-1
ii  powerdevil       4:5.14.5-1
```

If you need more information feel free to ask in a comment.

**EDIT:**
I found a case from not too long ago where exactly the same happened at: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=907301

Comment: Any logs? Possible approach: Log in via `tty2` and create a new user. If the new user is able to reach desktop all right then the problem is somewhere in your (i.e. the old user's) config (under `~/.kde/`?). Careful renaming/moving directories/files in `~/` and renaming/moving back can show you in which directory the culprit is, but you need to (try to) log in to desktop after each change. Then you go one directory deeper until you isolate the troublesome config file. If there are many troublesome files this may get complicated. Anyway it's good to know if a "scratch user" can reach desktop.

Comment: Or you copy your config to the "scratch user" gradually until it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

To close this question: The Problem was a version mismatch in the plasma-framework